# Java web application justified steps for form

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hey everyone thank you for taking your time to answering my question,
I am currently working with a java web application in eclipse quit a new to it,
the website contain a form and it takes a few steps/pages for user to complete it, in the header part i have a master page with few picture i wish to show user what step they currently on the form i had another page contain the form with submit logic etc.

Page 1: The master page, here is the page contain images and bit of logic which i hoping to show the process to user by displaying different picture.

```
<div style="text-align: center; padding-top:5px;" >
<%if (Steps == 1){ %>
    <img src="../../images/nivagationArrow1Highlight.png">
<%}else{ %>
    <img src="../../images/nivagationArrow1.png">
<%} %>
<%if (Steps == 2){ %>
    <img src="../../images/nivagationArrow2Highlight.png">
<%}else{ %>
    <img src="../../images/nivagationArrow2.png">
<%} %>
<%if (Steps == 3){ %>
    <img src="../../images/nivagationArrow3Highlight.png">
<%}else{ %>
    <img src="../../images/nivagationArrow3.png">
<%} %>
</div>
```

page 2 the form, which display above page like header :

```
**<jsp:include page="/form/Page1.jsp" flush="true"/>
<form id="Form" action="confirmation.jsp" method="get">
   <input id="FormMain" type="" name="formInput" value=""></input>
   <input id="1Form" type="" name="formInput" value=""></input>     
   <input class="submitBack" type="button" onclick="history.go(-1);"  />
   <input class="submitNext" type="button" onclick="javascript:submitForm();" />
</form>
```

page 3 simply have another form(check-boxs) and bunch of information etc.

page 4 showing message user had completed to the form and thanks them.

here is my question:
I tried to including java code <% int Steps=1;%> in page two and hope for master page will pick up the parameter and do the logic, but nothing happen. how can set a parameter in page to so the master page can read it ?? Is here another way or better approach ??

thanks again for your comment,appreciate !!

Comment: Don't use embedded Java code (scriptlets) in JSPs like that; it's a nightmare to deal with for a number of reasons. Use a proper MVC framework like Spring MVC that lets you perform your business logic in a controller method and then pass the results to a view for rendering. (For that matter, it looks like this might be a good candidate for Spring Web Flow.)

Comment: thanks for you comment, I have work with MVC before but for work matter I got to stick with the old java web architecture.

Comment: Even Oracle (Sun) recommends against using scriptlets. They were a bad idea, and the best solution is not to use them. If you can't use something halfway decent like Spring MVC or even Struts, look into writing a taglib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

page 2:

```
<% int Steps=1;%>
<jsp:include page="/form/Page1.jsp" flush="true">
    <jsp:param name="Steps" value="<%= Steps %>">
</jsp:include>
```

page 1:

```
${param.Steps}  || request.getParameter("Steps")
```